# Elpher loads for Gopher but not Gemini using Doom Emacs

Tags: package, doom

I am using the most up to date version of Doom Emacs, and I am trying to use Elpher to access Gemini pages. While it loads up Gopher pages just fine, any time I try to pull up a Gemini page I get a "Connection time-out message." Other users have suggested that it may be a TLS related issue, but I can't confirm that. They have stated that when they try the package with vanilla Emacs it works fine. Any suggestions on how I might go about fixing this?

Comment: Have you tried seeing if it works on your system with vanilla Emacs?

Comment: @JamesLeslie Indeed it does.

Answer (score 2):

So after comparing the TLS related variables between vanilla Emacs and Doomemacs, and playing around with some of the settings, the following allows me access to gemini websites:

```
(setq gnutls-verify-error 'nil)
```

I have no idea what security implications that has, but that gets things working at least.

Comment: According to the docstring, nil is the default and  tls checks are still performed via open-network-stream which still look secure: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Network-Security.html